# Stata doesn't save output file

Tags: regression, stata

I'm having difficulties to save the output of my regression. Stata is supposed to save the file as "output.dta" in the defined directory, however the file is not saved in this folder (and also nowhere else on my PC). Here is the final piece of code, where I want it to be saved:

```
if (`counter'==1) {
  save "C:\Users\Milla\Code\output", replace
  local counter = `counter' + 1
} 
if (`counter'!=1) {
cap append using "C:\Users\Milla\Code\output"
duplicates drop *, force
cap save "C:\Users\Milla\Code\output", replace
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why could this happen? The code runs well and throws no errors or warnings. But it also doesn't say "output.dta is saved" as it normally does, when one saves anything in Stata.

Thanks ahead and best regards,
Milla

Comment: The reason the code throws no errors or warnings, and does not say "output.dta is saved" (for the `save` within the loop), is because you have used `capture` to suppress all the output from your `append` and `save` commands within the loop. Try removing the `cap` from these commands and rerunning and see what Stata tells you.

Comment: What is the initial value of `counter`? You say that output.dta doesn't exist anywhere on the computer, so if `counter != 1` when you run this, it will try to `append` using a non-existent file and throw an r(601) file not found error. You precede the `append` with `capture`, so any errors will be suppressed.Although I suppose it should still `save` the file on the second `save` command.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 save "C:\Users\Milla\Code\output.dta", r
```